# magento bundle product with configuration

Tags: magento, configurable-product

I have a clothing store that runs under magento.
I have created several configurable items that allow the user to choose the size and color of the item they need.

How do i create a bundle of configurable items in magento in which the user can choose size and color for each item ?

For example say that i have 3 shirts in 4 sizes and 4 colors (16 options total * 3)
How can i create a bundle out of these 3 configurable items ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bundle configurable products in the current Magento CE. Each simple product in a bundle gets a bundle option value. What you want is a hierarchy of options, which is currently not possible with the core distribution. You would need a third party extension for this.

This [extension](http://ecommerce.brimllc.com/grouped-options.html) can do that with grouped products. There was also an extension for that with bundled products from Classy Llama Studios called Configurable Bundle Module, but it's dead.

Comment: do you know of any extension that does that ?

Comment: I've enhanced my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2, by default, you can't create the bundle configurable products in the current Magento CE. You need to go for the third-party extension or customize your core code to achieve the functionality.

There are some extensions that you can go for:
https://marketplace.magento.com/ewave-extendedbundleproduct.html
https://amasty.com/bundles-for-magento-2.html
https://firebearstudio.com/blog/how-to-add-magento-2-configurable-products-in-bundles.html

Through this extension, you are able to create/manage bundles that consist of configurable products through the admin panel or default API using the "Configurable Products In Bundles" extension.